# using the partial view in view page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I am using the normal view page. I have an AJAX form. When I click on the submit button on this form, i must be able to get the partial view updated. However I have tried with this option and found that the page request is needing a lot of time to render and I am sure that I messed up with this process more.

Here is the code that I have used,

1. Inside the controller,

   ```
   public ActionResult Index()
   {
       Users allUsers = new Users();
       if (Request.IsAjaxRequest())
       return View("Index", allUsers.GetAllUsers());
      else
       return View(allUsers.GetAllUsers());
   }
   ```

partial view [index.ascx]

```
    <%@ Control Language="C#"    Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<Model.Users>>" %>
   <table>
     <tr>
      <th>
     </th>
        <th>
             firstname
       </th>
       <th>
             userid
       </th>
       <th>
             dob
       </th>
       <th>
          address
       </th>        
  </tr>
  <% foreach (var item in Model)
      { %>
   <tr>
      <td>
         <%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) %>
         |
         <%: Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })%>
         |
         <%: Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })%>
     </td>
     <td>
         <%: item.firstname %>
     </td>  
     <td>
         <%: item.userid %>
     </td>
     <td>
        <%: String.Format("{0:g}", item.dob) %>
    </td>
    <td>
        <%: item.address %>
    </td>
   </tr>
          <% } %>
    </table>
   <p>
    <%: Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create") %>
     </p>
```

index.aspx page,

```
        <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
        <% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Index", new AjaxOptions
       {
           UpdateTargetId = "results"
       }))
           { %>
        <input id="Submit1" type="submit" value="submit" />
        <% } %>
        <div id="results">
            <% Html.RenderPartial("Index", ViewData.Model); %>
        </div>
        <h2>
            Index</h2>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>
                </th>
                <th>
                    firstname
                </th>
                <th>
                    userid
                </th>
                <th>
                    dob
                </th>
                <th>
                    address
                </th>
            </tr>
            <% foreach (var item in Model)
               { %>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <%: Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }) %>
                    |
                    <%: Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })%>
                    |
                    <%: Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })%>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%: item.firstname %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%: item.userid %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%: String.Format("{0:g}", item.dob) %>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <%: item.address %>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <% } %>
        </table>
        <p>
            <%: Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create") %>
        </p>
    </asp:Content>
```

Comment: your index.asx code is repeating in index.aspx as well why is that. plus you should show us actionresult that is handling Post request for the ajax form

Comment: it is too the same index action in the same controller. pls note that i have used the IsAjaxRequest method of the request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a nice challenge that I had solved the problem by myself. I had put the ajax links inside the usercontrol and then put the results div in the index page inside which the data was rendered using the same partialview control.

Then in the controller's action method, i called the return partialview(viewname and model data).

That's the trick.. got things completed. Anyways thanks for your assistance so far.

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
return PartialView("index",allUsers.GetAllUsers())
```

in case of ajax request. i suspect that controller is sending the Viewpage when u call

```
return View("index", allUsers.GetAllUsers());
```

which in turns render the partial page hence creating some kind of mess during the process. conversely, u can try renaming your partial page to index1 and

```
return View("index1", allUsers.GetAllUsers());
```

Comment: is there any good place where i can find the real working procedure for using partial view with ajax as it is a real waste of time for me to sit and wait for replies and post questions..

Comment: have a look at http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2009/05/19/ASPNETMVCAjaxBeginForm.aspx